# ClearCase and Eclipse: How to hide/ignore files?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, clearcase, ignore

I'm working with Eclipse and ClearCase and we're facing the problem that there's no "ignore"-feature in ClearCase and we're having regularly checked-in files that shouldn't have been checked in.

In Eclipse, I already found the "Ignored Resources" configuration in *Window -> Preferences -> Team* and have been able to ignore files that follow a specific pattern that way.

But what do I do if I want to

1. keep a folder and all its contents from being checked in (such as a target-folder containing classes and such) or
2. keep a single specific file that can't be matched by a pattern in "Ignored Resources" from being checked in?

**Update:** We're using the provided Eclipse-plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within eclipse itself, the current ClearCase plugin cannot specify files to ignores, and they will always show up with a native `ls -private` command as private files.

Only a dedicated GUI (like **CCRC** -- ClearCase Remote Client -- used as Rich Client Platform based on eclipse) has a way to [specify ignore files](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccperspective_ignore.htm).

Comment: The documentation you've linked to describes the same "Ignored Resources"-configuration that's also available in Eclipse but doesn't meet the 2 requirements stated above.

Comment: @Benedikt: indeed, my point was just to illustrate that only a dedicated GUI (eclipse + CCRC) could support that feature. ClearCase plugin alone (on top of eclipse) does not, because it only relies on native ClearCase commands (which do not include an "ignore file" feature, as far as I know)

Comment: @VonC I'm trying to ignore .class files from my view using CCRC. I do what you've post, but when I look for new resources show up all the .class files, why it isn't working? What I'm missing?

Comment: @Alavaros what pattern did you use in the Window > Preferences > Team category > Ignored Resources?

Comment: @VonC this is the pattern *.class

Comment: @Alavaros I see in the documentation `*.class*`, and make sure the checkbox is selected.

Comment: @VonC That's what I really have, exactly the same pattern.

Comment: @Alavaros Strange. What version of CCRC or ClearTeam are you using? And can you reproduce the issue in another view?

Comment: @VonC Versión: 8.0.0 and yes, in another view it happens too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say look at creating an entry in your configspec to exclude the target file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you are using the Eclipse plugin)

When you create a new file or folder, it asks you whether or not you want to add the element(s) to source control. If you simply click cancel on the popup, then it will be ignored until you specifically add it. So, ClearCase, in effect, asks you whether or not this is an ignored file as soon as you create it. If the files are being checked in, blame the people who checked it in, not ClearCase.

Comment: But they still show up in all searches and such as files that have not been added yet and if you're not really careful you will add those files to ClearCase.

Comment: If you're searching for View-private files for example you can't distinguish between files that haven't been added yet and files that you don't want ever to add.

Comment: @George, within Eclipse they probably don't show up during a find checkouts but if you use the Clearcase clients, they will.  The question is how to keep any Clearcase client from accidently checking in an 'ignored' file.

Comment: @George Also, if you delete the directory (like in a clean step of the Ant build script) and remake it, you'll have to cancel again and again. He (and actually me too) wants a way to say "if the directory is /dist, never ever check it in.

Comment: I do that twenty times a day, and I never get asked. I have not altered any settings from the install.